# Integration of $(1 - \cos\theta)^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer

Tags: integration

I came across this integral during a derivation I'm trying to figure out.

$$
f(N) = \int_0^\pi {\sum_{n=1}^N (1-\cos\theta)^n \, d\theta},\quad N \in \mathbb{N}
$$

Is there any sort of a general formula to this function for a given positive integer value of $N$?

I would appreciate any hints or some direction on the matter too. I've tried basic substitution of variables, but only got so far. The power $n$ makes it quite tricky.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to obtain. But if you allow some summation, if you open the brackets all you really need to be able to compute is $\int_0^{\pi}\cos^k(\theta)\,d\theta$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $\cos\theta=1-2\sin^2(\theta/2)$ and the [beta function identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Other_identities_and_formulas), we get

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi} (1-\cos\theta)^n \, \mathrm{d}\theta
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} 2^n \sin^{2n}(\theta/2) \, \mathrm{d}\theta
= 2^{n+1} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{2n}\varphi \, \mathrm{d}\varphi \\
&= 2^{n} B\left(\tfrac{1}{2},n+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)
= 2^{n} \pi \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k-\frac{1}{2}}{k} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2^n} \binom{2n}{n}.
\end{align*}

Alternatively, we may also write

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi} (1-\cos\theta)^n \, \mathrm{d}\theta = (-1)^n \pi 2^n \binom{-1/2}{n}. $$

Comment: Also maybe useful: $$\frac{\pi}{2^n}{{2n}\choose{n}}=\frac{\pi(2n)!}{2^n(n!)^2}$$